# Run linux commands through java

Tags: java, linux

This is what I am doing.

```
String a = "xx";
String command = "mkdir Desktop/"+a;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But its not working.

Comment: What do you think that should do? Why do you think so? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It should create the folder xx in Desktop.But nothing happens

Comment: Why do you think so? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It worked previously.But now its not working .I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: Does the folder already exist? I can see this not working if *the folder you're trying to make already exists*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a process, java should knows operating system commands. For example if you use command prompt then you should pass "cmd" for windows.

You may try this command instead of yours.

```
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C mkdir");
```